# Unity Main thread issue about ads

Tags: c#, visual-studio, android-studio, unity-game-engine

I almost complete my game on Unity. I'm just working on Admob to complete it. The problem is about rewarded videos. I have test ads and working on them but my reward function does not work properly. I am trying to debug it on Android Studio and the main error about the proccesses is:

> UnityException: get_transform can only be called from the main thread.
>       Constructors and field initializers will be executed from the loading thread when loading a scene.
>       Don't use this function in the constructor or field initializers, instead move initialization code to the Awake or Start function.
>           at (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.GameObject.get_transform(UnityEngine.GameObject)
>         at ContinueScript.ContinueGame () [0x00018] in C:\Users\s.gireniz\Desktop\bridgeball\BridgeBall\Assets\ContinueScript.cs:39
>
> ```
>   at AdmobManager.GiveReward () [0x0000c] in C:\Users\s.gireniz\Desktop\bridgeball\BridgeBall\Assets\AdmobManager.cs:272
>
>   at AdmobManager.HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded (System.Object sender, GoogleMobileAds.Api.Reward args) [0x00037] in
> ```
>
> C:\Users\s.gireniz\Desktop\bridgeball\BridgeBall\Assets\AdmobManager.cs:263
>
> ```
>   at GoogleMobileAds.Api.RewardBasedVideoAd.<.ctor>b__4_6 (System.Object sender, GoogleMobileAds.Api.Reward args) [0x0000f] in
> ```
>
> C:\Users\s.gireniz\Desktop\bridgeball\BridgeBall\Assets\G

I get this error like for every step on my rewarding script that I will share. I'm trying to fix it but for each line of code, main thread problem comes out. This is the error for the step I left and it comes out for "get_transform". How can I fix this clearly and not by doing it randomly ? And what is the reason of this error? Can you guys help me?

This is my Reward script below.

```
public void WatchTheAd()
{
    Debug.Log("Displaying Ad!!!!!");
    AdmobManager.instance.ShowRewarded();
}

public void ContinueGame()
{
    Debug.Log("Position Fixed !!!!!");
    //Target.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 1.5f, -200f);
    Player.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < Obstacles.Length; i++)
    {
        if (Vector3.Distance(Obstacles[i].transform.position, playerPos) < 
        200f)
        {
            Destroy(Obstacles[i]);
        }
    }

    Debug.Log("Is Dead False !!!!!");

    FindObjectOfType<PlayerCollision>().isDead = false;
    Destroy(ReplayButton);
    Destroy(WatchAd);
    Debug.Log("Buttons Destroyed !!!!!");

    GameObject Canvas = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Canvas") as GameObject;
    GameObject ContinueButton = Instantiate(AfterAdButton, new Vector3(0, 0, 1), Quaternion.identity)as GameObject;

    ContinueButton.transform.SetParent(Canvas.transform, false);
    Debug.Log("Button Instantiated !!!!!");
    Time.timeScale = 0f;
}

void Update()
{
    playerPos = Player.transform.position;
    WatchAd = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("WatchAd");
    ReplayButton = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("ReplayButton");
}
```

And this is the some lines of AdmobManager that I am trying to work on.

```
public void ShowRewarded()
{
    if (rewarded.IsLoaded())
    {
        Debug.Log("Ad Displayed!!!!!");
        rewarded.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        //FB.LogAppEvent("AdmobRewardedFailToLoad");
        GiveReward();
        RequestRewardBasedVideo();
    } 
}

public void HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded(object sender, Reward args)
{
    string type = args.Type;
    double amount = args.Amount;
    Debug.Log(
        "HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded event received for "
        + amount.ToString() + " " + type);


    // FB.LogAppEvent("AdmobRewardedView");
    Debug.Log("Reward Function Called!!!!!");
    GiveReward();

    this.RequestRewardBasedVideo();
}

private void GiveReward()
{
    Debug.Log("Reward Given!!!!!");
    ContinueScript.instance.ContinueGame();
}
```

Comment: right now I dont think theres quite enough there to count as [mcve] the biggest hint seems to be continuescript.instance.continuegame.. suggesting maybe its been offloaded to a different thread..

Comment: which is your `ContinueScript` and which is line `39`?

Answer (score 1):

Try using IEnumerator

```
   public void HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded(object sender, Reward args)
{
string type = args.Type;
double amount = args.Amount;
Debug.Log(
    "HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded event received for "
    + amount.ToString() + " " + type);

  StartCoroutine(AfunctionName());

}


IEnumerator AfunctionName()
{
 yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(0.1f);

 // FB.LogAppEvent("AdmobRewardedView");
    Debug.Log("Reward Function Called!!!!!");
    GiveReward();

    this.RequestRewardBasedVideo();
}
```

Give this one a shot. I had same problem this solved my problems :)